# SSIS how to redirect the rows in OLEDB Destination when the fast load option is turned on and maximum insert commit size set to zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am using a Fast load enabled OLEDB destination.In the error output there are 3 options Fail component,Ignore failure and Redirect.If I chose the Redirect It shows Fast load option enabled OLEDB can not redirect.Is there any alternative to handle the error going to happen with these type of Oledb destination(oledb with fast load option).

Comment: accept the answers of your previous questions as you accepted the answer of praveen on this question. green mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Fast Load ,insertion happens using single transaction .So in case if any error occurs the entire batch of rows needs to redirected .So its not possible to use `Redirect Option` with fast load .In order to redirect error rows you need to use either `Table or view` or write your `sql statements`.

Comment: tillykke..But how would I capture these erroneous rows.I can not change from fast load to view or table.Or how can I capture erroneous rows related to fast load?

Comment: If FastLoad is the only option ,then its not possible

Answer (score 2):

This post http://agilebi.com/jwelch/2008/09/05/error-redirection-with-the-ole-db-destination/ provides an interesting answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Because Fast load uses bulk operation, error rows redirection or ignoring is not allowed. You should not use fast load to redirect error.