# Finding the column throwing exception during data migration with SSIS from Oracle to MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am working on a data migration project. In current task, I have to select data from n number of tables from Oracle, join them and insert the data into a single SQL table. The number of rows are in millions.

Issue: There is data in Oracle which when we are trying to insert in SQL is giving exception. For example the datatype of the Oracle column is VARCHAR2 whereas in SQL it's int. The data is numbers. But there are few columns which have special characters like ','. This is one such example which will fail when we are trying to insert into SQL table. It's failing for many such columns.

I am using SSIS for this task. I am moving all the error id's of the rows into an error table which are throwing such error as mentioned in above example.

Question: I want the column name for which the insertion is failing for each row. Is there an option in SSIS? On error I want to store the id and the column name in an Error table.

Tried to search on internet, but didn't get anything. In SSIS, we do have option to configure the rows having Error. But didn't find that giving column name option to insert into a error table.

Edit: The data will come on daily basis i.e. the SSIS package will be executed daily.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but it looks like it might be what you need. [Get the Error Column Name in SSIS](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/get-the-error-column-name-in-ssis)

Comment: Process looks long...Will try this.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error Output contains many columns providing information about it.

> The list of columns includes the columns in the component input, the **ErrorCode** and **ErrorColumn** columns added by previous error outputs, and the **ErrorCode** and **ErrorColumn** columns added by this component.

If you are using OLEDB Destination, you cannot redirect the error rows while using Fast load option. And since you mentioned that

> The number of rows are in millions.

Then it is not recommended to use the Row-by-Row insertion.

If there are few columns, i suggest adding a Data Conversion Transformation and use its Error output to get the error information.

**References and helpful links**

- [Configuring Error Output Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/configure-an-error-output-in-a-data-flow-component?view=sql-server-2014#configuring-error-output-columns)
- [SSIS how to redirect the rows in OLEDB Destination when the fast load option is turned on and maximum insert commit size set to zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627250/ssis-how-to-redirect-the-rows-in-oledb-destination-when-the-fast-load-option-is)
- [Error Handling in Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/error-handling-in-data?view=sql-server-2014)
- [Error Handling With OLE DB Destinations](https://dzone.com/articles/error-handling-with-ole-db-destinations)